# Executing a script on background while the website browsing is ongoing on Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using Django and would like to background execute a long script at a certain stage while browsing the website pages. For example, for a user calculating the shortest distance and save in the database by comparing with available i.e. 5000 locations. At present, when the script execution starts then the page got frozen and couldn't allow clicking on the links or buttons.

I have tried using [Django Background Tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but that needs manually executing through command. Also, looked at Celery with Redis but I found Celery could be huge for this and due to that looking for an easy way.

Could you please share your advise to achieve my goal?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly your script do? Can you explain more?

Comment: After submitting the user signup form then it converts the zipcode to lat-lon and then find the short distance by comparing with available locations lat-lon.

Comment: I think you don't have many choices. You have to divide the script with your code for safety. Then you can consider cronjob or even consider other server, but I guess Celery is the best. Celery is not that hard way - it's quite simple with some libraries like django-celery

Comment: celery is the choice. If you think celery is too large and you have redis in hand,give  rq a try

Comment: In my opinion, you have two options Celery or [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). If this is the only script that will run in the background I would suggest you go with Celery, because it's simple.
But if there are going to be more such tasks later in your app, you must try Django Channels, I found it better.

Answer (score -1):

[extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra) is maybe what you need . And there is sample  similar to your question in doc